# Excel PivotTable bug? If Text column of source table has a month name, it breaks the A-Z sort in the pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel file which I can share with you, but here is how to recreate it:

1. In a workbook tab, create a table called "DataTable" with the two "Company" and "Score" columns as shown below.
2. Format the "Company" column explicitly as "Text". **You can even precede the entries with single quotes to force Excel to treat them as Text**: it won't change the behavior.
3. Below this table, create a simple PivotTable on "DataTable" with "Company" as a Row Field and "Sum of Score" as a Value Field.
4. In the PivotTable, Sort the "Row Labels" (Company) field "A-Z".
5. **You will see this, where the values "DEC" and "SEP" bubble to the top above the other A-Z values:**

[image: Screencap of PivotTable bug]

What apparently is happening is that Excel insists on treating anything that looks like a month name or abbreviation as its numeric equivalent, which sorts above the other A-Z text values.

- **Question 1:** Is this a confirmed bug?
- **Question 2:** How can I keep the desired values (like "SEP") but stop this from happening?

I am happy to upload an actual simple spreadsheet which shows this behavior.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on `Row Labels` Filter
2. Select `More Sort Options`
3. Select `More Options` (Bottom Left)
4. Uncheck `Sort Automatically every time the report is updated`
5. Ensure `First key sort order = No Calculation`
6. Refresh Pivot Table

[image]

Comment: That's good to know too, thanks! Unfortunately, that breaks the automatic sorting when the file is opened and the PivotTable is refreshed from dynamic data, so it would force my customer to have to remember to do a sort. 

It seems ridiculous that Excel doesn't honor the source data being formatted as Text... sigh. You'd think they would at least let me specify that at the field level without breaking the other features!

Answer (score 2):

That's because Excel thinks `SEP` and `DEC` are months names and sorts them according to `Custom Lists`. To prevent this, you need to go to `PivotTable` -> `Options` and uncheck `Use custom Lists when sorting` in the `Totals & Filters` tab

[image]

Comment: That definitely worked... thanks! I guess I'd better read up on Custom Lists.  :-)